# Display children of taxonomy term in parent taxonomy page

Tags: taxonomy-terms

i would like to print the children of taxonomy term in its parent taxonomy page.

For example there is a news portal and under Sports taxonomy term page i would like to print the children of Sports term:

SPORTS

## football #basketball #tennis ...

and then the latest nodes...

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Thanks for the replies but you are proposing to make a block in a different region of th page and print the child-terms using views.
I would like to print the terms under h1.title of the page term and before the nodes.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a view of taxonomy terms
2. Create a block display for the view
3. Add a contextual filter for vocabulary ID
4. Make the block show up on all vocabulary pages in the block settings.

Comment: This is a good solution if you're OK with using a Block to display the children.

Comment: Well yes it's not a good solution for someone who hates the Block module I suppose.

Comment: I love Blocks. They are very handy to drop into regions, and this works especially well with responsive themes. I've struggled with Panels playing nice with responsive themes, so I've been using blocks much more these days.

Comment: I tried but i get server error 500 when i create such block. I keep searching for the error.

Comment: When exactly does the server error happen? What's in the Apache log?

Answer (score 0):

It's really easy to achieve this using the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module.

Just install the views module and add a new view page fetching the taxonomy terms.
The procedure is pretty straightforward if you know how to use Views.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) for this, and the `Views content panes` sub module that comes with it. Download and enable the module (and the sub module) as usual, then...

1. Create a view of taxonomy terms
2. Add a contextual filter for a term id
3. Go to `admin/structure/panels`
4. Enable the `Taxonomy term template`
5. `Edit` the `Taxonomy term template`
6. Add a new variant
7. Add the `Taxonomy term view` you created earlier to the content, and pass the current page's taxonomy term id context as an argument to the View
8. Add the Taxonomy term `Description` content to the Panel
9. Add the `List of related items` content to the Panel